# How can I convert an escaped string to a bytea in postgresql (\ is not a binary digit) with Azure Data Studio

Tags: postgresql, bytea, azure-data-studio

This is probably a duplicate but I've been unable after quite some time to actually find out how to do this.

What I'm trying to do is simply roundtrip a binary value. I select it, then paste it into another SQL query.

I.e.

- I have a table with columns `id, data`
- I run this query in Azure Data Studio with the postgres extension: `select id, data from mytable`
- The output window shows this

```sql
id  data
58  b'\xaa\xb6\x87|-x\xf6\xd1\x80\xec\xd2\xed\x91\x1ebd\x924g\xcd\xaeVZ\x01\xf2\xa0\xb3\xd8\x16\xe1fC'
```

Now I'm trying to do a second query where I count things matching that one.

```sql
select count(*) from mytable where data = b'\xaa\xb6\x87|-x\xf6\xd1\x80\xec\xd2\xed\x91\x1ebd\x924g\xcd\xaeVZ\x01\xf2\xa0\xb3\xd8\x16\xe1fC'
```

And I get the error message **"\" is not a valid binary digit**

Most of the docs and other things I've found seem to suggest the `E'...'::bytea` syntax, so I do this:

```sql
select count(*) from mytable where data = E'\xaa\xb6\x87|-x\xf6\xd1\x80\xec\xd2\xed\x91\x1ebd\x924g\xcd\xaeVZ\x01\xf2\xa0\xb3\xd8\x16\xe1fC'::bytea
```

And I get the error message **invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xaa**

I've tried the `decode` function as other things suggested that:

```sql
select count(*) from mytable where data = decode('\xaa\xb6\x87|-x\xf6\xd1\x80\xec\xd2\xed\x91\x1ebd\x924g\xcd\xaeVZ\x01\xf2\xa0\xb3\xd8\x16\xe1fC', 'escape')
```

And that fails with the error **invalid input syntax for type bytea**

Why would the output format for binary data be something which is not a valid input format?
Hopefully this is not just Azure Data Studio being strange :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be Azure Data studio's behaviour, and not specific to postgresql.

When I run the same query using `psql` I get a sensibly formatted hex string which works fine in roundtrip queries, that looks like `\xbc6b702a12f8adb482ad517eca5af6407c9f172091242aa79845a17b4d479e2d` (note different data value but the format is correct)

I filed an issue against the postgresql addin for Azure Data Studio and hopefully it can be resolved that way.

Issue Link: https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio-postgresql/issues/204

As a workaround I will need to use `select encode(column, 'hex')` in all my queries

Answer (score 1):

When using hex values with `decode()` you need to use the `hex` option and provide only valid hex numbers:

```
decode('aab687', 'hex')
```

Alternatively you can prefix the hex values with a **single** `\x`, e.g.

```
'\xaab687'::bytea
```

However your string contains invalid hex values e.g. `\x1ebd`, `\x924g` and `\x87|-x` - not sure what the are supposed to be.

The "escape" syntax (e.g. using `E'...'`) requires [**octal** values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html#id-1.5.7.12.10), not hex numbers, so `E'\xaa\xb6...` should be `E'\\252\\266...`. The same is true when using the `'escape'` option for `decode()`